# Session destroys automatically after redirect laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4

My site worked last night. But in morning when I tried to login and login works but my `session` value doesn't display in another controller.

Here is my code sample,

I have route like this,

```
Route::get('/', array('before' => 'detectLang','uses' => 'ProductController@getIndex'));
Route::get('{slug}', 'DesignerController@getClient');

//DesignerController
public function getClient()
{
    Session::put('client', 'test');  // after login auth i am putting this
    //print_r(Session::get('client')); exit; //this one working here
    return Redirect::to('/'); // then redirecting to another controller
}


//ProductController
public function getIndex()  
{
  print_r(Session::get('client')); exit;
}
```

But that displays nothing. Don't know what is causing problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can solve this problem by creating a constructor and initialize the session from there.

Comment: Laravel automatically starts the session, there is no need to do this and this won't solve the problem.